# RequestMapping resource not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to code a controller that can handle dynamic URL

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/*/module/{file_id}" )
public String getModule( @PathVariable( "file_id" )
int fileId, Model model )
{
    return "redirect:../*/module/" + fileId;
}
```

The link:

```
<a href="../module/${ file_id }" >Spring Tutorial</a>
```

It produces `404: The requested resource is not available.` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you show me full of controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pass in an asterisk as a path placeholder.  I think what you would want to do is use a Path Variable like so:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath}/module/{file_id}" )
public String getModule( @PathVariable( "prePath" ) String prePath, @PathVariable( "file_id" ) int fileId, Model model ) {
}
```

You can also pass in regex to the Path Variables to further narrow your match:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:[a-zA-Z]+}/module/{file_id}" )
public String getModule( @PathVariable( "prePath" ) String prePath, @PathVariable( "file_id" ) int fileId, Model model ) {
}
```

This would be a good practice to do, in my opinion.